# Using Eclipse's JDT, how does one get an IType from a class name?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-jdt

Is there a simple, straightforward way to get an IType from a class name?  I think there must be some static method somewhere.  Basically, I'd like to do something like:

```
IType objectType = Somewhere.getType("java.lang.Object")
```

Does anybody know of something like this?  I have been searching in vain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given an IProject, one can use the IJavaProject#findType methods, e.g.

```
IType objectType = project.findType("java.lang.Object");
```

Comment: It took me a while, but I found the answer on one of the Eclipse forums.

Answer (score 1):

Look at `org.eclipse.jdt.core.search.SearchEngine`. I haven't tried it myself, I'm usually using the `ASTParser` with the Resolve option on (that's when you parse a source), but it should do the trick.