# How can I set the region (=set of java Elements) parameter in JDT TypeHierarchy?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=jdt_fundamentals&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.eclipsecon.org%2F2008%2Fsub%2Fattachments%2FJDT_fundamentals.ppt">JDT Tutorial an example code to get the type hierarchy using JDT.

[image]

How can I set the region (=set of java  Elements) parameter?
When I have code A that has SubClass B, and SuperClass C. How can I set the region?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code that I got hint from [this site](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/109644/) works fine.

```
IRegion region = JavaCore.newRegion();
for (IJavaElement i : javaProject.getPackageFragmentRoots())
{
    String elementName = i.getElementName();
    if (!elementName.endsWith("jar") && !elementName.endsWith("zip"))
        region.add(i);
    }

    NullProgressMonitor progressMonitor = new  NullProgressMonitor();

    // for getting a class hierarchy for type
    ITypeHierarchy typeHierarchy= type.newTypeHierarchy(progressMonitor);
    // for getting all the class hierarchies of the region in the project
    ITypeHierarchy typeHierarchy= javaProject.newTypeHierarchy(region, progressMonitor);
}
```

Related - [Why I got no super classes with getAllSuperclasses() in JDT API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295087/why-i-got-no-super-classes-with-getallsuperclasses-in-jdt-api/14329786#14329786)

Answer (score 1):

After reading the [IRegion Javadocs](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2FIJavaElement.html) and [Using Eclipse's JDT, how does one get an IType from a class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465365/using-eclipses-jdt-how-does-one-get-an-itype-from-a-class-name), I get the impression you should be able to create a region like this:

```
final IJavaProject project = ...;
final IProgressMonitor monitor = ...;
final IRegion region = JavaCore.newRegion();
region.add(project.findType("some.packagename.B"));
final ITypeHierarchy typeHierarchy = project.newTypeHierarchy(region, monitor);
```